# Advancing a Choker

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

I'm designing an encounter into which I'd like to include a Choker, but I'd like to make it lawful evil and give it levels in Monk.  Would its Constrict special attack (extraordinary ability) damage increase with those monk levels, or is it fixed at 1d3+3?

Comment: A Choker Monk is a frightening concept...

Comment: A choker *anything* is frightening because of the choker's quickness supernatural ability... if the DM says chokers still have it. The ability's omitted from the Aug. 2012 reprint of the *Monster Manual* but remains in the SRD.

Answer (score 4):

No, a Choker's constriction attack and its unarmed strike are unrelated attacks, and a Monk's unarmed damage modification only applies to the latter.

A Choker Monk would deal more damage than an ordinary Choker when using the 'damage your opponent' option in a grapple, but only a Choker's normal constriction damage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. The damage from the constrict attack is grappling. A monk's improved damage is for unarmed strikes (edit) and since "if you succeed ... you deal damage to the target as if with an unarmed strike", then yes, the monk ability would raise the choker's unarmed strike damage, and in turn it's grapple (or constrict). If you increase the monster's size along with hd, damage dice increase.